# How to determine if a NxN matrix with non-negative integer entries is a product of k square 0/1 matrices?

Tags: algorithm, matrix

So I'm suspecting this problem could be NP-complete or NP-hard at least in certain circumstances, but still, often for NP-complete problems there is a nice solution that runs much faster than naïve brute force.

My problem is, given an NxN matrix A, with non-negative integer entries, and an integer k > 1, how can we determine if A can be written as a product of k NxN matrices whose entries are all either 0 or 1?

Like I said, I think this problem may be

- NP-complete even for k = 2 but I maybe wrong,
- maybe it's polynomial time for k=2 or even for any fixed k or even for k not fixed.
- Also it may help to bound the non-negative entries in the target matrix A, to come up with good running times.

I would just like to find out good algorithms that run asymptotically faster (hopefully much faster) than brute force over all choices of 0/1 matrices to multiply.

Also, I apologize if this question is better suited on CS.stackexchange, if so, please let me know and I'll migrate the question. However we do have an `algorithm"` tag here, and since I suspect this problem is NP-hard, at least in one of its variants about whether k=2 or k is fixed or unbounded k, it's of more interest to me to just get whatever good algorithms may be available, e.g. that may work in polynomial time for fixed k or run in pseudo-polynomial time for arbitrary k but not polynomial time in general.

Comment: Probably best to just feed it to a constraint solver like z3 and see what happens.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I respect your intuition on this site so what you suggest may be the best. But e.g. for k=2, the equations turn out to each be a sum of N products of two distinct variables, such that the specified sum of products adds up to a desired non-negative integer. Similar structure holds for a product of k > 2 matrices, you get homogeneous polynomials that all have the same degree and number of terms and every variable has power 1 in all the terms. The fact that equations are such polynomials, and variables are 0/1, etc. makes me wonder if there is a direct line of attack here.

Comment: So if you have a 0-1 quadratic program of the form find vectors v1, ..., vn in {0,1}^d such that (constraints of the form vi . vj = ck), then that's most definitely NP-hard. Your problem loses the freedoms of setting d < n and of not requiring that the choices of i be disjoint from the choices of j, but I'm not seeing how that helps. Probably CS.SE would have an audience more inclined to complex algorithm design than SO.